# Зависает вся форма кроме listbox

Tags: c#, .net, асинхронность

Использовал async. Виснет всё, кроме listbox, кнопки не нажимаются.
Посидел подумал и пришёл к выводу - форма зависает при обработке pdf и docx файлов.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using TikaOnDotNet.TextExtraction;


namespace diplom
{   
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public string target_word;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        public void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog q=new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if(q.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = q.SelectedPath;
            }

        }

        public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
   
            if (Directory.Exists(textBox1.Text)==false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Директория не найдена","Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {
                on_click_search(textBox1.Text);
            }

        }


        void on_click_search(string directory)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            string[] alltxt = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] allpdf = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            string[] alldocx = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            if (alltxt.Length + allpdf.Length + alldocx.Length== 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Совпадений нет", "Результат поиска файлов", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            else
            {

                if (alltxt.Length != 0)
                {
                   'search_txt(alltxt);'
                   
                    

                }
                if (allpdf.Length != 0)
                {
                   'search_pdf(allpdf);'
                   

                }
                if (alldocx.Length != 0)
                {
                    'search_docx(alldocx);'
                    

                }
            }

        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            textBox1.Text=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            
          

        }

        async void search_txt(string[] alltxt)
        { 
            target_word = textBox2.Text;
            target_word=target_word.ToLower();
           
                
            await Task.Run(() => { Action ac = () => {
                foreach (string file in alltxt)
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file, Encoding.UTF8))
                    {

                        string str = sr.ReadToEnd();
                        string str1 = str.ToLower();
                        bool b = str1.Contains(target_word);
                        if (b == true)
                        {
                          listBox1.Items.Add(file);

                        }

                    }

                }
            }; if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(ac); else ac(); });


        }

        private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string str = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Process.Start(str);
                listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false);
            }
            catch 
            {
                
            }
            
        }

        async void search_pdf(string[] allpdf)
        {
            target_word = textBox2.Text;
            target_word = target_word.ToLower();
            SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
            
            await Task.Run(() => { Action ac = () => {
                foreach (string file in allpdf)
                {
                    f.OpenPdf(file);
                    string str = f.ToText();
                    string str1 = str.ToLower();
                    bool b = str1.Contains(target_word);
                    if (b == true)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(file);
    
                }
                }
            }; if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(ac); else ac(); });

        }

        
    async void search_docx(string[] alldocx)
        {
            target_word = textBox2.Text;
            target_word = target_word.ToLower();
            var textExtractor = new TextExtractor();

            
            await Task.Run(() => { Action ac = () => {
                foreach (string file in alldocx)
                {
                    string text = textExtractor.Extract(file).Text;
                    text = text.ToLower();
                    bool b = text.Contains(target_word);
                    if (b == true)
                    {
                        listBox1.Items.Add(file);

                    }

                }
            }; if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(ac); else ac(); });

        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

        
    }

    
}
```

Comment: `'search_txt(alltxt);'` что за апострофы по краям? Этот код вообще компилируется?

Comment: это мне предложило так выделить код. Первый раз задаю вопрос

Comment: код должен выглядеть так, как он выглядит в рабочем состоянии, исправьте пост

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async void search_pdf(string[] allpdf)
```

Никаких `async void`! Это только для событий, таких как `button1_Click`. Обычные функции должны быть типа `Task`:

```
async Task search_pdf(string[] allpdf)
```

```
search_pdf(allpdf);
```

А где `await` соответственно? Должно быть так:

```
await search_pdf(allpdf);
```

И `Invoke` тоже не нужен, насколько я понимаю вот этот:

```
if (InvokeRequired) Invoke(ac); else ac();
```

Продолжение асинхронной задачи по умолчанию делается в том же потоке, у вас и так всё происходит в потоке `GUI`. Хотя тут могу всех тонкостей не знать.

Есть и ещё проблемы в коде, но нужно начать с базовых вещей каких-то.

Примерно так это должно выглядеть, здесь только методы, которые я изменил.

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Директория не найдена", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        await OnClickSearch(textBox1.Text);
        MessageBox.Show("Поиск завершен", "Готово");
    }
}

private async Task OnClickSearch(string directory)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    string[] alltxt = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] allpdf = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    string[] alldocx = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.docx", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    if (alltxt.Length + allpdf.Length + alldocx.Length == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Совпадений нет", "Результат поиска файлов", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
    else
    {
        if (alltxt.Length != 0)
        {
            await SearchTxt(alltxt);
        }
        if (allpdf.Length != 0)
        {
            await SearchPdf(allpdf);
        }
        if (alldocx.Length != 0)
        {
            await SearchDocx(alldocx);
        }
    }
}

private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string str = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(str) { UseShellExecute = true });
        listBox1.SetSelected(listBox1.SelectedIndex, false); // зачем? чтобы я забыл, какой файл я выбирал?
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType().Name);
    }
}

private async Task SearchTxt(string[] alltxt)
{
    string target_word = textBox2.Text;

    foreach (string file in alltxt)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string str = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
                if (str.Contains(target_word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private Task SearchPdf(string[] allpdf)
{
    string target_word = textBox2.Text;

    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        SautinSoft.PdfFocus f = new SautinSoft.PdfFocus();
        foreach (string file in allpdf)
        {
            f.OpenPdf(file);
            string str = f.ToText();
            if (str.Contains(target_word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Invoke(() => listBox1.Items.Add(file));
            }
        }
    });
}


private Task SearchDocx(string[] alldocx)
{
    string target_word = textBox2.Text;

    return Task.Run(() => 
    {
        var textExtractor = new TextExtractor();
        foreach (string file in alldocx)
        {
            string str = textExtractor.Extract(file).Text;
            if (str.Contains(target_word, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Invoke(() => listBox1.Items.Add(file));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Стоит еще проверить на использование `IDisposable` ([документация](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects)), так как механизмы работы `TextExtractor` и `SautinSoft.PdfFocus` мне не известны, я не уверен, будет ли оно своевременно закрывать файлы.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135814/discussion-on-answer-by-crazyelf-----listbox).